# Removing \ file in command line only

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I accidently create a "\" file into my linux how to revert it. I tried rm \ (as it's the escaping character it didn't work), rm '\' and rm \\ nothing worked.

Comment: How do you escape the escape character? With another escape character of course.

Comment: Oh god I tried to show a double backslash and the editor of serverfault.com just escape it, so you were seeing only one blackslash. I need to escape this one too. Infinite looping question!

Comment: You can use backticks to represent a double-backslash. See my formatting test at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/67336#67336

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, you can't remove the file "\" directory, since \ is used as the shell escape character.

So instead, use the `\` character to escape the file/directory named "\":

```
$ rm -i \\
```

Here's my test:

```
# Make and verify the problem
$ touch \\
$ ls -ld \\
-rw-r--r--  1 me  me  0 Oct 11 16:59 \

# Remove the file:
$ rm -i \\
remove \? y
$ ls -ld \\
ls: \: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I tried it and it did the same thing as \, but I redid it with a new fresh termial and it worked. +1 for providing a proof.

Comment: Good thinking to try with a new terminal. It sounds like you old terminal might have gotten corrupt.

Comment: +1 for rm -i ; if all else fails, rm -i ./* will prompt for removal of every file individually... including the troublingly-named one.

Comment: I had the same problem recently with the tilde (~).  Solved it by using quotes:  rm "~", and it looks the same holds true for \: rm "\\".